# Integration Test Dependent upon a Database View

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, elasticsearch, junit, h2

The production environment uses SQL Server and the integration tests use an H2 database. We use a database view that joins a number of database columns, some of which use the `STUFF` function to create their field values in the view. The database tables for the production environment are created by Flyway scripts, whereas the tables used for the integration tests are either autogenerated by Hibernate or created via SQL scripts before the tests using the `@SQL` annotation. The `STUFF` function is not available for the H2 dialect and thus the views fails to be generated when the test class is run.

**Previous attempts at a solution**:

1. Adding `;MODE=MSSQLServer` to the databaseUrl property in the properties designated for the test application profile.
2. Defining a dummy function via an `ALIAS` that would act as the `STUFF` function for the integration tests.

Neither of these attempts has worked.

**Question**: How does one create a view like this for an H2 database?

**Background information**: An Elasticsearch index is reindexed programmatically using this view. The test class sets up data in the appropriate tables that are joined in the view and tests the processing of the data for the Elasticsearch index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STUFF()` is just shorthand for a more complex expression. These yield the same result:

```
DECLARE 
  @expr  varchar(64) = 'hello there',
  @start int = 6,
  @chars int = 4,
  @repl  varchar(64) = 'bye';

SELECT STUFF(@expr,@start,@chars,@repl);

SELECT LEFT(@expr,@start-1) + @repl + SUBSTRING(@expr, @start + @chars, 64);
```

Ignoring error handling for strings of 1 character and other edge cases like strings longer than 1 billion characters, you could create a function that abstracts `STUFF()` for you. On the SQL Server system, the function is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StuffForMe
(
  @expr nvarchar(max),
  @start int,
  @chars int,
  @repl nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT STUFF(@expr,@start,@chars,@repl));
END
GO
```

And on H2:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.StuffForMe
(
  @expr nvarchar(max),
  @start int,
  @chars int,
  @repl nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT LEFT(@expr,@start-1) + @repl 
    + SUBSTRING(@expr, @start + @chars, 1000000000));
END
GO
```

Your view then just references `dbo.StuffForMe` so it doesn't have to change between systems, you just have to deploy the two different versions of the functions independently.